# Does the use of 'piece' instead of 'coin' depend on the value of the coin?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns

I [ngram-viewered](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fifty%20pence%20piece%2Cfifty%20pence%20coin%2C%20one%20pound%20piece%2C%20one%20pound%20coin&year_start=1965&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfifty%20pence%20piece%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfifty%20pence%20coin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20pound%20coin%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfifty%20pence%20piece%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cfifty%20pence%20coin%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20pound%20coin%3B%2Cc1) 'a fifty-pence piece' and 'a fifty-pence coin' and found 'piece' to be more common than 'coin'.

But for 'a one-pound piece' and 'a one-pound coin', it is the opposite.

[image]

Any idea why? Does the noun 'piece' imply the idea of a fraction of a pound, of less than a pound?

Comment: This is just something I grew up with and I've never questioned it to be honest, but I would think it's because you're referring to coins that are a fraction of or less than a pound.

Comment: Funny, in AmE, a "fifty cent bit" is a contradiction in terms. They're no longer minted, but in the context of numismatist, a *bit* still means "half a quarter", as in the jingle "Shave and a haircut, two bits!" that was a every schoolboy's call-and-response secret knock. As for "piece", my take is that's used when you're discussing the coin *as an object*, as opposed to an amount of money. For the same reason, used more of oddities than of more run-of-the-mill currency: "a good piece", "a piece from Restoration America", and so on. Since 50¢ coins are less common, they're called *pieces*.

Comment: See also the Spanish dollar or "piece of eight": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dollar

Comment: @DanBron: sorry I made a mistake in the question, I meant 'a fifty-pence piece', not 'bit', and that's what I had ngram-viewered.

Comment: You Brits must have stronger pockets than we do in the US.  A one-pound coin would be far too heavy to carry around in your pocket.  (Seriously, "fifty-cent piece" is the only coin commonly called a "piece" in the US, and they are exceedingly rare -- basically collectors' items.  The others are "penny", "nickle", "dime", and "quarter", and, only very rarely, "xxx-cent pieces", while the 50-cent coin is occasionally a "half" or "half-dollar".  The "bit" expressions are pretty much only used in idioms.)

Comment: Oops!!   Make that "nickel".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: thank you for your excellent edit. Funny, I could not add 'a one-pound piece' on your link, but I was able to ngram-viewer 'a one-pound coin' and 'a one-pound piece'.

Comment: It appears that Ngram shows no records of "one pound piece" hence its non-appearance on the chart.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: with a hyphen it does, 'one-pound piece' or 'a one-pound piece, which is logical since the determiner/quantifier plus noun work as a kind of compound adjective.

Comment: The results for *one-pound piece* (with or without the hyphen) more often than not, refer to weights and not the coin, e.g. *one pound piece of dough*, *One pound piece of liver*, *You can prepare your salmon a variety of ways – baking at 350 for 10 minutes (for a one pound piece)*, *A one pound piece of iron was heated to 1000 °C and then quenched in a bucket containing....*  etc..

Comment: @Mari-LouA: got it! … at last!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to 1983, when the £1 coin was first issued, all British coins were referred to as "a such-and-such piece". I believe that the pound was treated differently because for some time both £1 coins and £1 notes were in circulation (they still are in Scotland), so there was a need to distinguish them in speech. "Piece" could have done that, but "coin" was used in contradistinction to "note".

Since then the £2 coin has been issued - no reason why that should have been "coin" rather than "piece", but, I guess on the parallel with £1, "coin" stuck.

**Edit** (after the answer was accepted): FumbleFingers points out that none of the pre-decimal coins were normally called "so-and-so piece". He's right, and I don't know what I was thinking of. (The British National Corpus has a few instances of "penny/threepenny/sixpenny/shilling/two shilling/crown piece", but they were not common expressions". I stand by my theory for why it is the "pound coin", though.

Comment: The £1 note is more or less out of circulation here now; I think the Royal Bank of Scotland does still issue a very small number of them, but I haven't seen one in years.

Comment: Back in the day, nobody called a *threepenny **bit*** a *threepenny coin/piece*. Sixpences were called just that (not sixpence pieces). A shilling was a shilling, never anything like a *shilling piece* (or God forbid, a *twelve-pence/penny piece*). A florin was either called that, or more commonly a ***two-bob bit***. Crowns (5s) didn't circulate much (people tended to collect rather than spend them if they turned up), but half-crowns were common, and I don't recall them ever being called anything including the word ***piece***. In short, our pre-decimalisation coins were never ***pieces***.

Comment: A sixpence could also be a tanner.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, the BNC has a few instances of all those except "half crown piece"; but I accept you are right, none of them were usually "piece". I don't know what I was thinking, and I'll edit the answer. I stand by my explanation for why the pound coin is the pound coin, though.

Answer (score 0):

The original 'coin' is what came from the mint.  These would be chiseled into pie shaped wedges by the common folk who needed a smaller amount (see 'pieces of eight').  When the government later minted smaller denominations, they retained the name 'piece'.

Comment: I heard that story about 50 years ago, but I've never seen it in print from a reliable source, nor have I ever heard anyone describe actually having some of these pieces (nor seen pictures of them).  So I'm somewhat skeptical of the story.

Comment: They are rare because most were melted down.  They were not legal tender.  Some people would unscrupulously cut the 'pie' into 10 'bits' instead of 8 to make a profit.

Answer (score -1):

The actual currency is the Pound, (or Dollar, or whatever).  So, if you have a coin which is equal to half of that currency (eg 50 pence/cents), you have a coin which can be seen as a "piece of a pound/dollar", hence "50 pence piece".  The pound coin isn't a piece of anything (as it's a whole unit of currency), so it's just called a coin.

Technically there's no reason not to call it a "50 pence coin", it's just a custom really.  It's still referred to as a coin when you don't use the value, eg *"I've got two coins in my pocket: a pound coin and a 50 pence piece."*

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I think *piece* refers to the chunk of metal, not fraction of the currency unit.

Comment: I think that this answer is unsupported speculation